# Sniffing API Calls from sidechat (sidechat.lol)

Tags: api, wrapper, packet-sniffers

I'm a college student who has an android phone and wants to use the sidechat app (sidechat.lol), which is only available on iPhone.
I'm trying to create an API wrapper for sidechat's API which will allow me to use it on Android (or on the web), but I'm not quite sure how to discover the api endpoints. (As far as I'm aware, there is no official public API)
Is there a simple way to do this, or do I need to do packet-sniffing on an iPhone running the app?
If I do need to sniff some packets, what's the best software for doing so?

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way to discover the API endpoints for Sidechat without reverse engineering the app. This can be done by decompiling the app's APK file (for Android) or by using a tool like Charles Proxy to sniff the traffic from an iPhone running the app.

Another way is to create a network proxy and connect to that proxy and perform actions in the program. And then have the proxy send the requests to where the packets should go.

Answer (score 1):

Yes!
Using Fiddler on a Windows computer you can set your [computer as a VPN](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/configureforios) that your phone will use and you can easily sniff all the HTTP requests.
I done it multiple times for various IOS apps

Answer (score 1):

Seems like someone already mocked it, maybe getting in touch with this dev helps: https://github.com/whoisronak/sidechat_api

Reaching out to the developers might also help ([contact@sidechat.lol](https://mailto:contact@sidechat.lol?subject=API%20Access%20/%20Android%20App)). I'd highly encourage you to be respectful and try the official way before trying to hack someones application. If all else fails and you do end up sniffing make sure you align with their [terms of service](https://www.sidechat.lol/terms-of-service) so you don't get into any legal trouble.